# QGraphicsScene addItem with Smart Pointer

Tags: qt, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a problem using smart pointers with Qt. I can´t figure out what is the reason for that strange behaviour.
Simple Setup:
I created a new Qt Widgets Application and dragged a QGraphicsView into the main window and only added the following Code to paint a circle:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QGraphicsScene"
#include "QGraphicsEllipseItem"
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
#include "QSharedPointer"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(ui->graphicsView);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    /* 1. raw pointer */
    QGraphicsEllipseItem* ell = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(100,100,50,50);
    scene->addItem(ell);

    /* 2. boost shared pointer
    boost::shared_ptr<QGraphicsEllipseItem> eSP(new QGraphicsEllipseItem(100,100,50,50));
    scene->addItem(eSP.get());*/

    /* 3. Qt shared pointer
    QSharedPointer<QGraphicsEllipseItem> eSP(new QGraphicsEllipseItem(100,100,50,50));
    scene->addItem(eSP.data());*/

    /* 4a. raw pointer as init parameter for shared pointer
    QGraphicsEllipseItem* ell = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(100,100,50,50);
    boost::shared_ptr<QGraphicsEllipseItem> eSP(ell);
    scene->addItem(eSP.get()); // using shared pointer */

    /* 4b. raw pointer as init parameter for shared pointer
    QGraphicsEllipseItem* ell = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(100,100,50,50);
    boost::shared_ptr<QGraphicsEllipseItem> eSP(ell);
    scene->addItem(ell); // using raw pointer */
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

As you can see I tried some variants. The first one ist the only one that works. It paints a circle in the center of the QGraphicsView. But for my project I need a smart pointer implementation. But all the smart pointer implementations do not paint the circle.
Am I making any mistake???

Especially 4b confuses me most. The only difference to 1 is that I am putting the raw pointer additionally into a shared pointer and that won´t work

Please help me!

My environment:

```
- Linux Mint 17.1
- qt-sdk 2ubuntu3
- boost 1.54.0.1
```

Comment: Why are you using smart pointers in this case? When you add an item to the scene, the scene takes ownership of the item.

Comment: the code above is just simple for testing purposes. In my project I call a function that returns a smart pointer to a derived QGraphicsEllipseItem and I want to paint that

Comment: Well in this code your smart pointers are going out of scope at the end of your `QMainWindow` constructor. That causes your graphics items to be deleted. That is why you don't see them anywhere.

Comment: Thats it. I had a bug in my project code, so the graphics item had only this one reference. So the smart pointer logic deleted it at the end of the local function. - Thank you, thuga